# Sqoop not supporting extended ascii as delimiters

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, sqoop, extended-ascii

I'm trying to sqoop import from teradata and the columns have some hash values which include most of the ascii characters.

**Hence i'm trying to mentioned delimiter as extended ascii (Dec-128) Ç (cedilla), hdfs files has some junk as Ã**

**Data in hdfs using cedilla**

> 4182Ã27-1746296ÃCRYSTAL DAWN MARTIN DCÃ

The problem is since the data has much junk it almost have all the ascii characters in data.
Also i'm unable to escape delimiters in the data using **ignore-data-delim** cos it's not supported in Teradata.

Comment: Hadoop uses UTF-8, not your _"extended ascii"_ vague wording for whatever single-byte codepage maps `Ç` to decimal 128 >> not the standard Western European code pages anyway?!?

Comment: In other word, this in not "junk" but the result of your lack of experience in text encodings... BTW I would be surprised if Teradata text contains ASCII control characters such as `7` (Bell)  or `11` (VTab) that are completely obsolete nowadays, hence can be used as safe separators.